# UITableView setSelected(_:animated:) only works on last cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a typical UITableView. It's one section, and pulls data from an array of objects.

The only cell that will select is the last cell in the table view. I am not selecting multiple cells. When `data` is set to `[0, 0, 0, 1]` the last cell will be selected, but any other combinations (like `[0, 0, 1, 0])` will not select the cell.

I am using XCode 9, Swift 3.2, iOS 11

This is the view controller, which is being presented on top of another view controller:

```
class ProblemedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let data = [0, 0, 1, 0]

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if data[indexPath.row] == 1 {
            cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to select multiple rows?

Comment: I would add the property observers `willSet` and `didSet` to `currentQuestion`. On `willSet` deselect the row represented by `oldValue`,  on `didSet` select the row represented by `newValue`